# Node.js doesn't execute code after MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have no idea what I did wrong, it's supposed to output onto console "Query Initiated" after it grabs the result but nothing is logged and I have no idea what I did wrong. Yes, I know the syntax is ugly, I ran a prettifier over it and now it is incredibly ugly and I am too lazy to manually go through 200+ lines of code to fix it.

```
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM pedodb WHERE ID='${msg.author.id}'`),
    function (err, result) {
        query.on('result', function (err2, result2) {
            callback(null, rows, fields);
        console.log("Query Initiated")
```

Comment: From the docs `You MUST NOT provide a callback to the query() method when streaming rows.`  You have to choose between using a callback `function (err, result) { ...` getting all the results at once.  Or if you want to process partial results as they arrive: `query.on('result'`. You cannot use both at the same time. https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#streaming-query-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback should be associated with the `query` function.

And the practice of using parameters is that they should be in separate parameters otherwise there are chances that it can lead to SQL injection.

```
connection.query(`SELECT * FROM pedodb WHERE ID = ?`, [msg.author.id],
    function (err, result, fields) {
        callback(null, rows, fields);
        console.log("Query Initiated")
})
```